# Django - 'Feed' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to add this form to my project and i get this error:

**'Feed' object is not callable**

When I was using only models.py it was working. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Feed


class FeedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feed()
        fields = [
            'post'
        ]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Feed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.TextField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

views.py

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FeedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
    else:
        form = FeedForm()
    return render(request, 'feeds/feed_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model should be just the class name of model not the instance of model.

So your forms.py should look like this

```
from django import forms
from .models import Feed


class FeedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feed
        fields = [
           'post'
         ]
```

For more information you can see this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/